ERROR al ELIMINAR un REGISTRO -- CRUD PYTHON-TKINTER
def EliminarEstudiantes(idEstudiantes):
try:
        cone=CConexion.ConexionBasedeDatos()
        cursor=cone.cursor()
        sql = "DELETE datosperso SET datosPerso.idEstudiantes= %s;"
        valores = (idEstudiantes,)

        cursor.execute(sql,valores)
        cone.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount,"Registro Eliminado")

        cone.close
        
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Error al eliminar los datos {}".format(error))

EL ERROR ME LO MARCA EN LA LINEA QUE ESTÁ EL SQL

Claro, porque esa no es la sintaxis de DELETE en SQL. Investiga cómo hacer un delete en el SGBD que estés utilizando (MySQL/MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server...)

Gracias trabajo en MariaDB, no se en que versión ya que lo instale junto al  XAMM 7.4.33. Seguiré investigando.
